# PDO Bug: fetchColumn() VS count()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table containing 3 rows. I am trying to loop through all the rows but I am not getting the right amount of rows.

My code is as follow:

```
$result1_prepare = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$result1_prepare->execute();

$num = $result1_prepare->fetchColumn();
$result1 = $result1_prepare->fetchAll();


echo $num; //OUTPUT 3
echo count($result1); //OUTPUT 2

if($num > 0){

    foreach ($result1 as $x => $row) {

        //LOOPING only 2 times, 1 row is not showing

    }


}
```

The fetchAll() function is only returning 2 rows. How come?

Comment: you're using `fetchColumn` to count the number of rows?

Comment: See `PDOStatement::rowCount` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @dirt: `... a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed ...`

Comment: @RocketHazmat right, more specifically see Example #2 which is what hes trying to do

Comment: Are you sure there are 3 *rows* in that query, and not 3 *columns*?

Comment: Spudley's Razor: If the options are either a bug in your own code or a bug in a popular and well-known library, you should always start by assuming it's a bug in your code rather than in the popular, well-known library.

Comment: @dirt you don't need rowcount with fetchAll

Comment: Thanks Guys. I am now using rowcount for counting the rows.

Comment: Try to avoid rowCount if you can for performance reasons.  Some PDO backends seem to implement it as a separate query, i.e. "SELECT count(*) ......".  Personally if I really need to know the number of rows, I either do an explicit query with "SELECT count(*)" - or I do a fetchAll and count that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code contradicts with your words. most likely you are calling fetchColumn before fetchAll - so, fetchColumn snatches one row from the resultset, leaving only two for fetchAll.

Anyway, you need none of these

```
$stm = $DB->prepare("SELECT * table");
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();

foreach ($data as $x => $row) {

       //LOOPING only if there was data returned. no need to check the number

}
```

Comment: You are correct. FetchColumn was snatching one row from the result set. ALso, I am now using rowcount for counting the rows.